# Difference between the different DuplexChannelFactory<TChannel> constructors

Tags: constructor, wcf

what is the difference between the three following constructors, and when do i use each of them. sorry for this basic question :

- DuplexChannelFactory(InstanceContext)
- DuplexChannelFactory(Object)
- DuplexChannelFactory(Type)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms585874.aspx

Thanks!

regards

thomas